# replacing text between brackets from text in file

Tags: sed, server, client

I have configured the server instance in code

```
"instance": [
   { "address": 127.0.0.1,
     "port": 6514
},
{"address": 127.0.0.1,
 "port": 6515
}
]
```

I'm also having file(/root/home/inst.txt) which has a format

```
{ "address": 127.0.0.1,
     "port": 6514
},
{"address": 127.0.0.1,
 "port": 6515
},
{"address": 127.0.0.1,
 "port": 6516
}
```

I want to replace server instances in code from file.
I had tried

```
 sed -e '/"instances": \[/,/\]/{/r /root/home/inst.txt/!d}'
```

but failed

Comment: When you had showed the result you wanted, you might have had more answers. And more cases, explaining why you don't want `echo '"instance": ['; cat root/home/inst.txt; echo "]"`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ne '/instances/,/\]/!{p;b};/instances/{p;r addrFile' -e '};/\]/p' mainFile
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n`.

If the current line is **not** between `instances` and `]`, print the current line.

If the current line is between `instances` and `]` and matches `instances`, print the current line **and** the addFile.

If the current line is between `instances` and `]` and matches `]`, print the current line.

Alternatives:

```
sed -e '/instances/!b;p;r addrFile' -e ':a;N;/\]/!ba;s/.*\n//' mainFile
```

Or:

```
sed -e '/instances/{p;r addrFile' -e ':a;N;/\],/!s/\n//;ta;D}' mainFile
```

Or:

```
sed -ne '/instances/{p;r addrFile' -e ':a;/\],/!{n;ba}};p' mainFile
```